# Custom control Image not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, custom-controls

I have a custom control. It has an image. I have exposed the ImageURL attribute in the custom control code by creating a new attribute called ButtonIconImgSrc as follows:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("Gets or sets the logo image path")]
public String ButtonIconImgSrc
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        return iconImg.ImageUrl;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            iconImg.ImageUrl = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I compile the customeControl code to create a dll and then add the dll to my web site solution so i can drag and drop it onto my designer view or dynamically create it. Everything seems to work great in designer, i drop it on, set my custom atributes and looks good.

..... but the img does not show when i compile and run the site in a browser. nothing gets set correctly, its all lost by the time it gets back to the calling code - labels and textboxes and widths and heights etc. I want to create this customcontrol dynamically, not use the designer but same issue.

Below is the code that calls the above 'set' method, except after it comes back from th eset method its still blank.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCustomButton tb = new myCustomButton();
    tb.ButtonIconImgSrc = "~/imgs/target_logo.png";
    pnlButtons.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

I see the code above being hit and the string "~/imgs/ibc_foh.png" being set in the myCustomButton code and that code exits and everything looks good. When the debugger gets back to the calling class (my websites Page_Load) the attribute tb.ButtonIconImgSrc is still blank, "". And so the image does not appear.

Updated: problem solved. I misunderstood the lifecycle of the control, the image was being overwritten in the createChildControls method

Comment: Where is `iconImg` defined (from your property)?

Comment: What *does* show in the page?  What is the actual markup being rendered?  How does that markup differ from what you expect?  (Hint: The value of `iconImgUrl` doesn't look like a URL...)

Comment: I see source code for the rest of my custom button. Just the src for the images="";

Comment: Oh, ok, so iconImageUrl is meant to set the 'image.ImageUrl' of the custom button's image - is that the wrong att to use for a file that sits in a local dir?

Comment: correct, you should be giving it a URL path not a local filepath. Your server still needs to serve the image. however, it is possible to turn images into a base64 string value and embed them.

Comment: so if the image is on the local filesystem (windows server)  how should i set that. Note, when i set it to this in designer it sees it, it just doesnt work when i actually run the page

Comment: generally, I serve my files using a completely different virtual directory that is set up on my web server to point at a folder. the easiest way is to just add the resources into a common folder 'media' in your project, and reference them. You could use Context.Server.MapPath for as well.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Updated question wiuth some new findings... i see that if i add the images to my solutiuon then i can refer to them like "~/imgs/target_logo.png". This works for one but not both so il keeplooking, surely i dont need to add all possible images, can i not just look at a directory?

Comment: @Brett, i added my imgs to my soln, but im gettig weird results, not always the same. Out of 2 imgs, Sometimes one img shows, never the other. If one img shows i get the others alt message but sometimes none show. Can somebody tell me howe to load an image from a directory normally, forgetting the custom button stuff, just show an img

Comment: the image will be served as a resource (uri).. so your marksup and stylesheets link/ref it via uri. `"http://localhost:<port>/media/myimg.png"` .. websites work through virtual directories, that map filesystem directories to addresses. That's the 'Hosting' aspect. your web.config is a way to configure (add/remove/modify) the modules of ASP.NET (a component to IIS) so that your web application can do nifty dynamic handling of pages and resources.

Comment: what is an image? well, like any other file, it's a series of bytes that follow some sort of standardized format.. IIS, or your web hosting environement, does not typically validate the format and structure of the contents it servers (that's not it's responsibility).. all it does is stream bytes and sets the appropriate headers.. specifically the `content-type:"image/png"` and `content-length:<sizeoffileinbytes>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. I misunderstood the lifecycle of the control, the image was being overwritten in the createChildControls method

Answer (score 1):

Create/Add a Generic HttpHandler page to your project.

in the function 'ProcessRequest'. there will be a HttpContext object (called context).
do as followed:

```
public class YouHandlerPage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        // REVIEW AND PROCESS THE REQUEST (i.e. ...
        //    context.Request.QueryString
        //    context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
        //    context.Request.Form


        string fDirectory = @"C:\Users\john\Desktop\";
        string fileName = "ibc";
        string fileExt = "png";

        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/" + fileExt;
        //let context.Response.ContentLength be specified by the following WriteFile method
        context.Response.WriteFile(Format.String("{0}{1}.{2}", fDirectory, fileName, fileExt));
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false;} }
}
```

now, **run** your web application.. and goto `localhost:<portassigned>/<handlerpagefilename>.ashx`

Where `locahost:<portassigned>` is your domain (or IIS Express assigned), and `<handlerpagefilename>` is whatever your named you added GenericHandlerPage (which should end with **.ashx**).

When you visit this page, you should get your image..

---

### Further Review

---

- review Registering Routes to map to your HandlerPage.
- review HttpModules as an alternative to httphandler pages

Comment: Hi, thx for the post but i dont think this tackles the issue as i now understand it. I can dynamically create a image and set its imageURL to a image in the solution and that works. What i cant see to do is set an image in my custom button. I see the 'set' method getting hit, the images imageURL being set within the set method with the correct string but when the code comes back to the main class the custom attribute is blank ie "". I think il update th equestion to better reflect this as i am now clear its not a permissions issue

Comment: found the problem, I misunderstood the lifecycle of the control, the image was being overwritten on the createChilControls event.